# Ошибка при работе с файлом базы данных: sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Задача, которую не выходит решить: написать на Python простейший код, который будет показывать таблицу из БД.

Исходные данные:

```
Файл test.sql ЭКСПОРТированный ИЗ PhpMyAdmin
Дериктория с файлом test.sql
Таблица test_table фнутри файла
```

Код test.sql

```
-- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (i686)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
--
-- Table structure for table `test_table`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `iD` int(3) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */
--
-- Dumping data for table `test_table`
--
LOCK TABLES `test_table` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `test_table` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `test_table` VALUES (5);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `test_table` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

Далее, написал на Python3 следующий скрипт:

```
import sqlite3
import os.path
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("/path/to/test.sql"))
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "test.sql")

with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("Select *From Test_table")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print(results)
conn.close()
```

Что уже сделал:

1. Пытался создать файл с расширением .sqlite, используя онлайн конвертеры или с помощью скрипта mysql2sqlite.sh
   При использовании онлайн конвертеров никаких файлов с расширением .sqlite НЕ получается. На выходе имеем таблицу .csv и какой-то файл column. Абсолютно не понимаю, как с ними работать
2. Пробовал импортировать файл в MariaDB и оттуда генерировать файл базы данных. Опять получается не база данных, а её дамп с расширением .sql
3. Генерировал из PhpMyAdmin файлы с другими расширениями
   Скрипт на Python то ругается, что это не файл базы данных, то говорит, что не видит там никаких таблиц в то время, как вижу я
4. Юзал вдоль и поперек [habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/321510/)
5. Искал советы на англоязычном стеке

Ничего не помогло.

Как можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113739/discussion-on-question-by-enoch-python-------sql).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вам уже неоднократно написали в комментариях, SQL файлы предназначены для обработки на стороне соответствующей СУБД (Система Управления Базой Данных). Т.е. SQL код выполняется непосредственно в соответствующей СУБД.

Соответственно SQL файлы невозможно выполнить / запустить из Python, *не отправив* SQL код на выполнение СУБД.

Для того, чтобы прочитать данные из БД при помощи Python нужно выполнить следующие операции:

1. установить Python модули / драйвера  для работы с нужной вам СУБД
2. установить `SQLAlchemy` - как универсальную прослойку для работы с БД (можно обойтись и без `SQLAlchemy`, но тогда код может сильно отличаться для различных СУБД)
3. собрать правильную строку подключения к БД (чаще всего проблемы возникают на этом шаге). Советую внимательно посмотреть [примеры подключения к различным СУБД](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#database-urls) в документации по SQLAlchemy.
4. дальше можно читать данные из таблиц любым удобным вам способом. Для удобства и простоты я воспользовался [модулем Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) - данные в нем можно прочитать одной строкой. Если делать это обычными средствами, то вам придеться итерироваться по строкам и столбцам и код будет гораздо более громоздким.

---

Вот вам код для чтения данных из MySQL таблицы из Python, вывода на печать и сохранение в CSV файл и Excel таблицу:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

db_host = "mysql_server_hostname"
db_user = "mysql_user_name"
db_pwd = "mysql_password_for_specified_user"
db_name = "test" # MySQL database name
db_charset = "utf8mb4"

db_connection = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pwd}@{db_host}/{db_name}?charset={db_charset}"
conn = create_engine(db_connection)

# читаем все строки из таблицы `mysql_table_name` в Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM mysql_table_name", conn)

# вывод данных на экран (по умолчанию показывается максимум 15-20 строк, т.е. только первые и последние строки)
print(df)

# сохранение данных из таблицы в CSV файл
df.to_csv("/path/to/table_name.csv", index=False)

# сохранение данных из таблицы в Excel файл
df.to_excel("/path/to/table_name.xlsx", index=False)
```

PS для того, чтобы этот код работал правильно необходимо сначала установить используемые Python модули:

```
pip install pandas
pip install SQLAlchemy
pip install PyMySQL
```

Comment: добрый день! Провел все манипуляции с установкой указанных библиотек. В теминале все successfully. Перезагрузил систему. Однако, при попытке импортировать модули pandas, SQLAlchemy, PyMySQL система их не видит, будто я и не устанавливал. Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQLAlchemy'

Comment: @Enoch, вы их импортируете как у меня в ответе? Регистр букв важен!

Comment: @Enoch, советую создать новый вопрос об установке и импорте модулей...

Comment: да, все так же. Это видимо какой-то баг системы. Ни у кого таких проблем не возникает.