# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, sql, debian

Использую Eclipse на Debian. Все необходимые модули типа

```
sqlalchemy
pymysql
pandas
```

установлены [должным образом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185847/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-sqlite3-databaseerror-file-is-not-a-dat/1186272?noredirect=1#comment2068877_1186272). Представленный код ниже прекрасно работал.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: <utf-8> -*-
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

... код тела программы ...
```

Стоило установить на винт другую linux подобную систему, РЯДОМ (ПОВЕРХ) Debian как все слетело. Теперь при запуске выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/way_to_path/dataBases.py", line 3, in <module>
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
     **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'**
```

Ребята, как исправить проблему? Что могло пойти не так?

Comment: Попробуйте установить модули заново

Comment: В `pip freeze` есть `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: [связанный вопрос...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1002447/211923)

Comment: @AlexeyR. я так и сделал. Например, pip install SQLAlchemy. Ответ: Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy: /usr/local/lib/Python3.7/dist-packages (1.3.20)

Comment: скорее всего у Вас с версиями питона путаница. Зайдите в `/usr/bin`, запустите оттуда `./python --version`. Что показывает?

Comment: @gil9red да. Написано SQLAlchemy == 1.3.20

Comment: @AlexeyR. показывает Python 2.7.16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте в своём файле поменять `#!/usr/bin/python` на `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

Вы установили пакеты для 3го питона (*Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy: /usr/local/lib/**Python3.7**/dist-packages* ), а интерпретатором выбран питон версии 2 (*показывает **Python 2.7.16***).

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло...

Comment: В каталоге `/usr/bin` выполните `ls -la | grep "python3 "`. Что возвращает?

Comment: Там достаточно большой перечень строк. Есть ли смысл их здесь перечислять? Количество символов в комментарии, я думаю, не позволит все перечислить

Comment: Решился вопрос! Я просто сменил #!/usr/bin/python3 на #!/usr/local/python3    УРА!!! Все заработало!! :-) Не понятно, почему pathon3 стал располагаться в local правда... Черный ящик, честное слово.